# Create User delegation key from azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I try to create a User delegation key from azure portal.

[image]

No matter what privileges I'm assigning to myself, I hit the same error message

> You don't have permissions to grant read access. You can still create
> a shared access signature, but you'll need an RBAC role with
> additional permissions before you can grant that level of access to
> your signature recipient.Learn more about Azure roles for access to
> blob data

So far I have the following the roles assigned :

[image]

And the link provided [in the error message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas#assign-permissions-with-rbac) says I need one of the following :

- Contributor
- Storage Account Contributor
- Storage Blob Data Contributor
- Storage Blob Data Owner
- Storage Blob Data Reader
- Storage Blob Delegator

So it should work, but it doesn't. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***The error usually occurs if you don't have required roles/permissions assigned to create User delegation key.***

Please **note** that in order to create user delegation key, ensure to have role that includes action like below:

```
Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/generateUserDelegationKey
```

The above action is included in the below **roles**:

- Storage Blob Data Contributor
- Storage Blob Data Owner
- Storage Blob Data Reader
- Storage Blob Delegator

Try assigning either `Storage Blob Data Contributor` / `Storage Blob Data Owner roles` as you didn't assign.

Please check at what **`scope`** you have assigned the role, make sure to assign the roles at the level of the **storage account**, the **resource** **group**, or the **subscription**.

***I tried in my environment, and got the same error when the roles are not assigned:***

[image]

***After assigning the roles, I am able to create user delegation key successfully without errors.***

[image]

If still the error persists, try creating an **[Azure Support ticket](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/options/)**.

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

[Create SAS tokens for containers and blobs with the Azure portal | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/create-sas-tokens#use-the-azure-portal)

[azure-docs/storage-blob-user-delegation-sas-create-cli.md at main · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs · GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/storage/blobs/storage-blob-user-delegation-sas-create-cli.md#assign-permissions-with-azure-rbac)

Comment: Hey! Sorry I've been busy last days. It works, thanks :)